# syntax of sql-statements in python

Tags: python, sql

I got this code to save some values in a Sql-DB via python. But it doesn't work. Could you please help me to find the problem?

```
def saveValue(art, value, timestamp):
    # Missing: Check if table setting exists or create it
    # First check if row exists
    cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM setting WHERE parameter=%s', art)
    existing = cursor.fetchone()
    if existing[0]==0:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO setting (parameter, wert) VALUES (%s, NULL)', art)
        db.commit()
    # Update row
    cursor.execute('UPDATE setting set value=%s WHERE parameter=%s', value, art)
    db.commit()

    # Check if measure-table exisits or create ist
    cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES LIKE measure_%s', art)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if not result:
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE measure_%s (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, time int(11), value float(6), PRIMARY KEY (id))', art)
        db.commit()
    # Insert measure value
    sql = 'INSERT INTO measure_%s (time, value) VALUES (%s, %s)'
    args= art, timestamp, value
    cursor.execute(sql,args)
    db.commit()
```

Maybe it is even possible to optimize/minimize the code?

Comment: what does not work? Do you get an error message? If so which one? Please provide the traceback if present

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get any error message. But if I put a print "ok" in the last line, there is no output. If I delete the second half of the script, there would be a print-output. So there is something wrong in the second part, but I don't know how to find the mistake. Further more I think it is written a little bit too complicated, isn't it?

Comment: what is the first half exactly? and which DB engine are you using? SQLite?

Comment: The second half is "Check if measure-table exisits or create is" to the end. I'm using: import MySQLdb